# spring security get all concurrent sessions for a user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring security form based login app. Now suppose I have 2 users login in with same credentials(say using 2 different devices or browsers), How can I get those two concurrent users details?

I am aware that we can get the list of all logged in users using SessionRegistry, But how will I achieve the above?

Comment: What do you mean by *users details*?

Comment: I mean getting the Principal of both users

Comment: See [SessionRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html). Method `getAllPrincipals()` will give you all principals. Also see [Keep Track of Logged In Users with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-track-logged-in-users).